# reference mutltiple selections or registers for shell-command-on-region

Tags: shell-command

<kbd>C-u M-|</kbd> is wonderful for things like running `sort` a region. But I've wandered into an interesting place. I wan to run `join` or `comm` on two regions in a buffer.

```
# region 1
a 1
b 2
z 26

# region 2
a foobar
b 2
c 3
```

and I want `join -j1 <(region 1) <(region 2)`.

I think registers or secondary selection could make this easier than the albeit already quick

```
  # select region 1
  M-| cat > /tmp/r1
  # select region 2
  M-| cat > /tmp/r2
  # position cursor below
  M-| join -j1 /tmp/r[12]
```

I don't see anything about referencing registers or selections in `shell-command-on-region` but maybe there is a similar command, universal argument, or package? 
Would it be outrageous to point to files through /proc or a la [elfuse](https://github.com/vkazanov/elfuse)

(Edit: example output -- current buffer)

```
# region 1
a 1
b 2
z 26

# region 2
a foobar
b 2
c 3

# join -j1 /tmp/r[12]
a 1 foobar
b 2 2

# comm -12 /tmp/r[12]
b 2
```

Comment: This cries for a simple elisp function that merely automates the steps in your example. Are you interested in elisp based solutions? In fact, even a macro may be possible, I admit there would be a tricky part with handling the temporary files, but if you dedicate a directory to it you could just use fixed names, like you already do in the example.

Comment: What @q.undertow said: define a keyboard macro or an Elisp command.

Comment: Library [`zones.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zones.el) might be able to help with the joining, depending on what you mean; dunno.

Comment: Could you show explicitly what you want the result of your operation to be, given the original buffer text you show?

Comment: @Drew, sorry for the confusion. I am using this buffer line an org-babel notebook. I'd run the commands on buffer selections and get the output below it. I start with the original posted buffer, and end with the final output buffer. I added the `#` comment lines to indicate what happened (as I do in my notes)

Comment: Please put any clarifying info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions should stand on their own. Thx.